# unable to verify that docker engine is installed by reaching pull rate limit

Tags: docker, installation

I wanted to install docker on my laptop to test and run my web applications on it's containers instead of virtual environment (I am running ubuntu desktop version 20.04 LTS and using pipenv for virtual environment). After signing up at hub.docker I went to  https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/(hub.docker manual to install docker on ubuntu), I decided to install using the repository and typed following commands in terminal

1.`sudo apt-get update`
2.`sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common`
3.`curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -`
4.`apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88`
after running last command I got desired result which was
" pub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [SCEA]
9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A  E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88
uid           [ unknown] Docker Release (CE deb) docker@docker.com
sub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [S]"
As my system is amd64 I continued by
5.`sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"`
6.`sudo apt-get update`
7.`sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`
8.`sudo docker run hello-world`
then at this point I got
"Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit.
See 'docker run --help'."
Questions

1. Did I do anything wrong in installation process?
2. How can I run to pull rate limit when I have just installed it?
3. Have docker correctly installed on my laptop? (when I type `docker --version` in terminal I get  "Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61"
4. What should I do now?

Comment: Are you in an office or shared network environment?

Comment: I share mobile data in my phone with laptop. Does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

I just installed docker myself and encountered the same error.

I don't think you have installed it wrong (since I'm a newbie myself I cannot confirm it 100%), but I solved this error by creating an account in docker website and then logged-in from CLI.

to create an account go to: https://www.docker.com/pricing
and then use signup for free.

To login through CLI type:
`docker login -u your-username`
and then it asks for your password, and then you are good to go!